# How to map data between iOS application and Rails webservice with backend legacy SQL database

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, restkit

I am using a Rails webservice to mediate between an iOS app and a legacy SQL Server database.

Using Active Record and a slew of ruby gems I have managed to generate a set of models which map directly to the SQL database.

However, the objects in my application depend not on any single one of the aforementioned models, but consist of data represented by several models at once (the SQL tables utilize foreign keys).

The question is: what is the best way to map (into Core Data) between my app and the ruby models?

I was thinking it would make sense to generate 'intermediate' models which correspond directly to my app's objects, and which consist of many 'belongs_to' statements to these existing models.  Is this the purpose of belongs_to? Is there a better way? Am I even understanding the capabilities of Rails or am I making things too simplistic or complex?

Thanks in advance!!

EDIT:  For example,

I have a Core Data Entity 'Game Instance' which consists of the following attributes:
 - name
 - denom
 - lines
 - credits
 - reels
 - type
 - sectionCode
 - positionCode

The pertinent SQL tables / Rails models are as follows:

'GameInstance'
- GameID (FK)
- LocationID (FK)

'GameConfiguration'
- GameID
- MachineID (FK)
- DenomID (FK)
- Lines
- Credits
- Reels

'Game'
- MachineID
- Type
- Name

'Denom'
 - DenomID
 - DenomValue

'Location'
- LocationID
- SectionID (FK)
- PositionID (FK)

'Section'
- SectionID
- SectionCode

'Position'
 - PositionID
 - PositionCode

As you can see, this single Core Data entity would be dependent on several of the Ruby models.

Comment: Add some details of your core data model. It sounds like you have full control of the output JSON and you want to know what to provide to make mapping the relationships easiest?

Comment: Hey @Wain- I updated the question with some context.  I have the models in Rails, but they do not map directly to my Core Data entities.  I wonder if I need to make 'intermediate' models in Rails, or if this can be handled in Core Data?

Comment: Your JSON is really your intermediate 'model'. Your rails can traverse its model to gather all of the information that makes up a single requested game instance and return it as nested content in a JSON object. I don't know rails but I'd say that belongs_to just makes your traversal easier and the model more clear...

Comment: @Wain- Okay, that makes a lot of sense actually.  I don't really know Rails either which is the big issue here, haha.  I guess I would use a controller to consolidate the information and return it as the JSON object that I want... Now to figure out how to do that.  Thanks for your help! (PS: Do I need to do the @ Username to notify you, or are you automatically alerted of comment responses?)

Answer (score 1):

You would probably have an easier time not using RestKit, and setting up the app to work with what you already have, not what you want. Network connections are pretty trivial on iOS, especially with fantastic block-based libraries such as [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). That will be the path of least resistance.

Comment: Mapping arbitrary models into Core Data using RestKit is trivial, and I have already been successful with this for existing models.  This issue is that the existing models mean nothing until I can establish relationships between the entities and their attribute data, that is, I have no use to map the existing models.  So I wonder if it is possible to make 'intermediate' models in Rails for my app to map to? Or is there a way to make this data meaningful by establishing relationships in Core Data?